# Velleman, exercise 23 section 3.3 on families of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, fake-proofs

I'm self-studying *How to Prove It*, by Daniel Velleman. The indicated exercise asks us to criticize an incorrect proof of the following incorrect theorem, and to provide a counterexample. I'd like to verify my answer. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Incorrect Theorem**: *Suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are families of sets. If $\cup\mathcal F$ and $\cup\mathcal G$ are disjoint, then so are $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$.*

The incorrect proof goes like this (paraphrasing): Suppose $\cup\mathcal F$ and $\cup\mathcal G$ are disjoint and suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are not. We can choose a set $A$ which belongs to both $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$. Now $A\in \mathcal F$ implies $A\subseteq\cup\mathcal F$ and $A\in \mathcal G$ implies $A\subseteq\cup\mathcal G$. But this contradicts the supposition that $\cup\mathcal F$ and $\cup\mathcal G$ are disjoint. So $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ must be disjoint. $\square$

The only flaw I can spot is on the sentence "But this contradicts..." because it tacitly supposes that $A\neq \emptyset$. My counterexample is $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$ and  $\mathcal G=\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}$, so that: $\mathcal F\cap \mathcal G=\{\emptyset\}$, $\cup\mathcal F=\{1\}$, $\cup\mathcal G=\{2\}$ and $\cup\mathcal F\cap\cup\mathcal G=\emptyset$.

Do you agree or I'm way off mark here?

Comment: You can modify your counterexample a bit making it even more trivial. Suppose that $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{G} = \{\emptyset\}$.  Then $\bigcup{\mathcal{F}} = \bigcup{\mathcal{G}} = \emptyset$. One can easily see that the intersection of the unions is the empty set, whereas the intersection of families is the set $\{\emptyset\}$ which is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I agree. You are entirely right. In fact, you spotted the only problem with that proof. If we add that $\emptyset\notin\mathcal{F}$ or $\emptyset\notin\mathcal{G}$, then the proof will be correct (and the statement will be true then, of course).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta rápida!